# How to get AD properties for user of web browser

Tags: asp.net, webforms, active-directory

This code gets me properties of an AD user in our organization, specifically the user that the web site is running as, a service account (so the results are the same no matter what user is running the web site):

```
DirectoryEntry entry = UserPrincipal.Current.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
if (entry != null)
{
    foreach (string name in entry.Properties.PropertyNames)
    {
        Response.Write(entry.Properties[name].Value.ToString() + "</br>");
    }
}
```

However, what I need is to get those properties for the user who is running the web browser. I would think I could get those from HttpContext, but can't find that principal or a GetUnderlyingObject() method that way.

How do I get that same list of AD properties for the user who is logged into the Windows machine and running the web browser?

Comment: This isn't really available. You can sometimes find things in the HTTP headers that _seem_ to be what you want, but that's just the default. _It's trivially easy for users to override this to show any username they want._ If you're running a web app, where your code is limited to the browser, you're gonna need some kind of actual authentication piece. You can use SAML/OAuth to make this easier, but your users will still need to log in.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thanks, Joel.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "the user who is logged into the Windows machine and running the web browser". If you want to do that without the user authenticating to your website, then Joel's comment is accurate - you can't do it. But if you're using Windows Authentication in your website and you want to refer to the user currently logged into your website (which may not be the same user that's logged into Windows, but in most cases probably is) then erastl's answer is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`string user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();`

You should be able to find more info on using AD in webforms via google search, if you need to do something more with that info other than print it :)